# gt Table not being displayed on shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, gt

I am working on a shiny app for a job application and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I managed to display this table on a tab panel inside the main panel:

```
prestamos_complete %>% 
  filter(Estado.solicitud %in% c('Approved', 'Rejected')) %>% 
  group_by(Nombre,Cedula, Genero) %>% 
  summarise(tasa_rechazada= sum(Estado.solicitud=='Rejected')/n(),
            total_solicitudes = n()) %>% 
  filter(tasa_rechazada!= 1 & tasa_rechazada!= 0) %>% 
  arrange(desc(total_solicitudes)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  slice_head(n=10) %>% 
  gt() %>%
  fmt_percent(columns = tasa_rechazada, decimals = 1) %>% 
  fmt_number(total_solicitudes, decimals = 0) %>% 
  tab_options(table.background.color = '#fdae6b',
              column_labels.border.top.color = 'black',
              column_labels.border.bottom.color = 'black',
              column_labels.border.lr.color = 'black',
              table_body.hlines.color =  'black')
```

The table looks good and it works all fine.

But then I try to add a input that I defined as follows:

```
selectInput(
        inputId = "estado_solicitud",
        label = "Seleccione Estado Solicitud:",
        choices = c(unique(prestamos_complete$Estado.solicitud)),
        selected = c('Rejected', 'Aprproved')
      )
```

So the output on the server looks like this:

```
output$gttable1 = render_gt({
    prestamos_complete %>% 
      filter(Estado.solicitud %in% input$estado_solicitud) %>% 
      group_by(Nombre,Cedula, Genero) %>% 
      summarise(tasa_rechazada= sum(Estado.solicitud=='Rejected')/n(),
                total_solicitudes = n()) %>% 
      filter(tasa_rechazada!= 1 & tasa_rechazada!= 0) %>% 
      arrange(desc(total_solicitudes)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      slice_head(n=10) %>% 
      gt() %>%
      fmt_percent(columns = tasa_rechazada, decimals = 1) %>% 
      fmt_number(total_solicitudes, decimals = 0) %>% 
      tab_options(table.background.color = '#fdae6b',
                  column_labels.border.top.color = 'black',
                  column_labels.border.bottom.color = 'black',
                  column_labels.border.lr.color = 'black',
                  table_body.hlines.color =  'black')
```

But as soon as I add that filter, the table stop being displayed and I have no clue why is that. As I defined the select input with all the possible options being select, It does not have any sense that the table disappears.

If anyone can help me I would really preciate it. I know this is better with a reproducible example but im not good creating it.

Already thanks to all the community.

Comment: `as soon as I add that filter` << does it means when you added this filter or when you change the value of input filter?

Comment: Maybe you can update this typo `selected = c('Rejected', 'Aprproved')` to `selected = c('Rejected', 'Approved')`

Comment: It means when I added that filter

Comment: Have you tried to fix the typo? Is it fixed?

Comment: I fixed the typo but still the same problem. Also I change the selected argument to that to make it clear that it wasn't the problem. Previously it was: ```selected = c(unique(prestamos_complete$Estado.solicitud))``` so the selected options were all the possible options.

Comment: What is this `selectInput`? Can it hold multiple values? Or you need to add `multiple=TRUE` [like this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798042/r-shiny-how-to-use-multiple-inputs-from-selectinput-to-pass-onto-select-optio)

Comment: Cant believe it was that. Thanks so much @HeinzSiahaan , if you want to write an answer I would happily mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the typo and add `multiple = TRUE` on `select_input`, so your code will be like this:

```
selectInput(
        inputId = "estado_solicitud",
        label = "Seleccione Estado Solicitud:",
        choices = c(unique(prestamos_complete$Estado.solicitud)),
        multiple = TRUE
        selected = c('Rejected', 'Approved')
      )
```

Comment: Just excellent response.